# How to pass parameter in Object's clone function in Java

Tags: java, clone

All:

I am wondering if I define a class implements Clonenble:

```
public class cloneobj implements Cloneable {
    String name;
    public cloneobj (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.clone();
    }

}
```

I wonder how can I give name to new clone object?

Thanks

Comment: What does "give a name to an object" even mean?

Comment: @markspace Just like call constructor function

Comment: So what's the point of cloning the object if you don't want to clone it?

Comment: @markspace Because I want to keep other field, this object can have other member field other than name.

Comment: You shouldn't use clone then.  Make a new object, copy the fields manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your clone method yourself:

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return new cloneobj(name);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to call `super.clone();`

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    cloneobj cloned = (cloneobj)super.clone();
    cloned.name=this.name; //maybe (String)this.name.clone(); could be used
    return cloned;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am too new to Java. : (   So this means that I do not need to call super.clone(), I thought super.clone may do some hidden job other than constructor...

Comment: Yes, you must call `super.clone()` or it won't work.  The answer is wrong.

Comment: @maskacovnik Thanks, as MarkSpace said: "Yes, you must call super.clone() or it won't work. The answer is wrong".  Is your edit answer is to correct previous answer or both ways work?

Comment: I am not sure if you have to call `super.clone()`. This is a native method which should be called, but in the other hand, constructor should create a copy as well as clone method @Kuan (source of Object class here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Object.java#Object.clone%28%29). I haven't tested any of my examples...

Comment: @maskacovnik Thanks I think the edited answer is enough for me.

Comment: `cloned.name=this.name` is redundant, `clone()` already does this. http://ideone.com/94gSTv